# How to edit protected files on mac

Tags: macos, vim, sudo

I've just bought a new mac, I'm trying to edit the `DockMenus.plist` file from `Dock.app` to remove finder from dock like I've done with my previous macs. However, on saving, `vim` prompts this error:

```
"DockMenus.plist" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

This is after I tried using `sudo` and rooting myself with `sudo -i`. this file doesn't seem to be able to write to, even when I tried `:w !sudo tee %` it just returned `shell returned 1` and nothing happens.

What's the fastest thing I can do to edit these files? Thanks!

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x You can only disable SIP from Recovery.

Comment: @Tetsujin Is there literally no other way to do this?

Comment: If there was, the linked QA would be unlikely to have gathered 400 upvotes.

Comment: If your new mac has Mojave, try this: System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Full Disk Access and allow it. Are you in this mode?

Comment: @Yoan Yes I do have mojave, will try now.

Comment: @Yoan it can only allow apps and 'vim' is apparently not an app..

Comment: TextEdit instead?

Comment: @Yoan It didn't work, TextEdit threw warnings about locked files and won't let you edit it even after granted full disk access.

Comment: Some explanations here: http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/ - i do not know if you are in this case...

Comment: @Yoan Enabling ‘Full Disk Access’ won't help with write access to SIP restricted files. For completeness, you wouldn't add vim to that list if you wanted to grant it Full Disk Access, but rather Terminal. TextEdit does not have the ability to elevate itself to root to edit files, you'd have to launch TextEdit as root originally to be able to edit files owned by root and protected by SIP when SIP is disabled. Still, you'd need to boot to recovery to disable SIP to be able to edit the file that's mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to edit a file that's part of macOS, a SIP restricted file. You need to [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/208478/37797) to be able to have write access to the file as root. Run `csrutil disable` from Recovery, then edit the file as root. You can re-enable SIP with `csrutil enable` once you've made the change.